# gitignore all node_modules directories and subdirectories

Tags: node.js, npm, gitignore, ignore

If I put this in .gitignore:

```
node_modules
```

it doesn't appear to ignore subdirectories that contain a node_modules folder.
So my guess is that this will work:

```
*/node_modules/
```

does anyone know what the right syntax is for ignore files to ignore matching subfolders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore sub-directories indeed, and the syntax you proposed is correct, here is a working example of a .gitignore i'm using :

```
# Bundler
Gemfile.lock
bin/*
.bundle/*
*/test/
```

Comment: I think it should be  `*/test/` and that will ignore any directory named "test" and it's contents right?

Comment: Correct, i didn't copy the whole file, and missed the last forward slash ;)
Good catch

Comment: ty, MrCholo approves this message